# How to store two values in php variables, that have been passed via get JSON

Tags: php, jquery, serialization

I want to store the two values in php, within calcsums.php, after taking them from Jquery via GET JSON . How can I do this? I don't want to store them in Jquery, I want to store them  in  PHP (in calcssums.php)

**My Form**

```
<form action="" method="post" name="formsubmit" id="formsubmit"   >
<h1> Process </h1>
<p> operation type always robot </p>
<br> <br>
Number of welds: <input type="number" name="numberofwelds" id="numberofwelds"  >
<br> <br>
Number of construction welds: <input type="number" name="numberofconwelds" id="numberofconwelds"  >
<br> <br>
<h2> Outputs </h2>
<br> <br>
Robot in/out: <input type="text" name="robotinout" disabled>
<br> <br>
Weld time: <input type="text" name="weldtime" disabled>
<br> <br>
Controlling cycle: <input type="text" name="concycle" disabled>
<br> <br>
Total time(secs): <input type="text" name="totaltimesecs" disabled>
<br> <br> <br> <br>
<input type="submit"  value="Calculate" id="submit" name="submit">
<div id="result"> </div>
</form>
```

**Jquery**. Gets values from two fields. Not the whole form

```
 var formData = $('#numberofwelds, #numberofconwelds').serialize();
    $.get('calcsums.php', formData, sumresults);
```

Comment: Where are the PHP variables you mention?

Comment: @jon Sorry. Don't think my question is clear. I want to store the two field values in PHP in calcssums.php. So that I can then do some calculations on them.

Comment: You can access those values with `$_GET['numberofwelds']` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var numberofwelds = $('#numberofwelds').val(),
    numberofconwelds= $('#numberofconwelds').val();

$.get( 
     "calcsums.php", 
     { numberofwelds : numberofwelds , numberofconwelds: numberofconwelds }, 
     sumresults  
);
```

Then you can retrieve the value in PHP:

```
$numberofwelds = $_GET['numberofwelds'];
$numberofconwelds = $_GET['numberofconwelds'];
```

Comment: "This answer is not useful" is *the* reason for a downvote. If you believe that it *is* actually useful, could you explain why? In what way would this solve the problem? Hint: you will find it hard to explain, because the problem has not even been defined properly.

Comment: OK, now it's going in the right direction. The JS part is still irrelevant.

Comment: @Felix Sorry. My question can't have been clear enough. I want to store the field values in php, in calcsums.php . Not store them in javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take all form datas as JSON use the following:

```
var formData = $( "#formsubmit" ).serialize();
```

If you want to take only some fields make a JSON with that field vales like:

```
var formData  = {numberofwelds:$('#numberofwelds').val(), numberofconwelds:$('#numberofconwelds').val()}
```

Comment: @Sherin Jose I want to store the two values in php, within calcsums.php, after taking them from Jquery via GET JSON. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You can access the values in the php file `(calcsums.php)` as `$_GET['numberofwelds']` and `$_GET['numberofconwelds']`

Comment: Thank-you for the support